# How to upgrade windows powershell 5.0 to 5.1

Tags: powershell

How to upgrade powershell from 5.0 to 5.1 in windows 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default powershell in window 10 is 5.1, you can check it by `$PSVersionTable`, even if you dont have ps 5.1, you can try instal WMF5.1 from this location https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616, for details visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/installing-windows-powershell?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: This is only true from the Anniversary Update builds onwards. Older builds of Win 10 came with PS5.0

Comment: Is there any way to upgrade powers hell without updating Windows 10

Comment: As far as I know, not with Windows 10 currently.

Answer (score 1):

To do this I believe you need to upgrade Windows 10 itself, to the Anniversary Edition (or later). I don’t think you can directly install WMF 5.1.

The direct installer for WMF 5.1 is just for Windows 7 Service Pack 1, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2.